# building a javascript invoice system

Tags: javascript, php

ok, I'll try this again, my bad.

I am trying to build a very simple php invoice system just for inputting data, writing it to a database, and ultimately sending the Info to a file for printing. The problem I am haviung, besides being pretty new to javascript is getting a grand total from multiple lines of items and totals. I will post the page I have started to work with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add()
{
var a = parseInt(document.frm.A.value);
var b = parseInt(document.frm.B.value);
var result = parseInt(document.frm.Result.value);
var result=a*b;
document.frm.Result.value=result;
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
}
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="frm">
 <p>&nbsp;</p>

<table width="66%" border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#B80000">
<td width="60%"><div align="center">Item Description</div></td>
<td width="11%"><div align="center">Price Per</div></td>
<td width="15%"><div align="center">Quantity</div></td>
<td width="14%"><div align="center">SubTotal</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="center">
  <input name="item" type="Text" id="item" size="100" >
</div></td>
<td><div align="center">
  <input name="A" type="Text" id="A" onChange="add()" size="5" >
</div></td>
<td><div align="center">
  <input name="B" type="Text" id="B" onChange="add()" size="5" >
</div></td>
<td><div align="center">
  <input name="Result" type="Text" id="Result" size="8" >
</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="center"></div></td>
<td><div align="center"></div></td>
<td><div align="center"></div></td>
<td><div align="center">
TOTAL:
  <input name="Total" type="Text" id="Total" size="8">
</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

So I am trying to figure out how to take the total from the SubTotal column and have it summed in the TOTAL field. If I have multiple rows, i need to have all the subtotals added together. Been working on it for days and cant figure it out.

If I have multiple rows setup this way:

```
  <form name="frm">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <table width="66%" border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#B80000">
  <td width="60%"><div align="center">Item Description</div></td>
  <td width="11%"><div align="center">Price Per</div></td>
  <td width="15%"><div align="center">Quantity</div></td>
  <td width="14%"><div align="center">SubTotal</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><div align="center">
  <input name="item" type="Text" id="item" size="100" >
  </div></td>
  <td><div align="center">
  <input name="A" type="Text" id="A" onChange="Adder()" size="5" >
  </div></td>
  <td><div align="center">
  <input name="B" type="Text" id="B" onChange="Adder()" size="5" >
  </div></td>
  <td><div align="center">
  <input name="Result" type="Text" id="Result" size="8" >
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><div align="center">
  <input name="item2" type="Text" id="item2" size="100" >
  </div></td>
  <td><div align="center">
  <input name="A2" type="Text" id="A2" onChange="Adder()" size="5" >
  </div></td>
  <td><div align="center">
  <input name="B2" type="Text" id="B2" onChange="Adder()" size="5" >
  </div></td>
  <td><div align="center">
  <input name="Result2" type="Text" id="Result2" size="8" >
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><div align="center">
  <input name="item3" type="Text" id="item3" size="100" >
  </div></td>
  <td><div align="center">
  <input name="A3" type="Text" id="A3" onChange="Adder()" size="5" >
  </div></td>
  <td><div align="center">
  <input name="B3" type="Text" id="B3" onChange="Adder()" size="5" >
  </div></td>
  <td><div align="center">
  <input name="Result3" type="Text" id="Result3" size="8" >
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><div align="center"></div></td>
  <td><div align="center"></div></td>
  <td><div align="center"></div></td>
  <td><div align="center">
  TOTAL: 
  <input name="Total" type="Text" id="Total" size="8" onChange="Adder()" >
  </div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

will the javascript work when I add the other elements to it? or am i going in the wrong direction

Comment: what is the problem you're facing exactly? is it not doing anything? are you getting an error message?

Comment: the first row is working fine, but everything I have tries to get the grand total to show up in the TOTAL box has not worked, no error message, just does nothing. I dont know what to do for that next step

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of your current code, the following would work:

```
function add() {
    var a = parseInt(document.frm.A.value);
    var b = parseInt(document.frm.B.value);
    var result = parseInt(document.frm.Result.value); // <-- This line is unnecessary
    var result = a * b;
    document.frm.Result.value = result;
    document.frm.Total.value = result; // I added this line
}
```

**EDITED:** I came up with a slightly cumbersome method of scaling the above with multiple rows as follows.

Give specific ID's to each of your rows and their result pairs like so:

```
<input name="A" type="Text" id="A1" onChange="add(1)" size="5" />
<!-- ... -->
<input name="B" type="Text" id="B1" onChange="add(1)" size="5" />
<!-- ... -->
<input name="Result" type="Text" id="Result1" size="8" />
```

(the next row would then have the number 2 added where you have 1 above)

You could then use the following js:

```
function add(row) {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('A'+row).value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('B'+row).value);
    if (a > 0 && b > 0) {
        document.getElementById('Result'+row).value = a * b;
        document.getElementById('Total').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('Result1').value) + parseInt(document.getElementById('Result2').value);
    }
}
```

I'm sure this could be done in a better way, but I believe it's a good one to start with...

Here you can **[play with a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uEG5v/)**.

Comment: perfect, worked great. The next part I am having trouble with is multiple rows, each one with its own item, cost, and subtotal, how would I get all the subtotals to add up in the total box. Do i follow the same build as I have or do I have to restructure it completely

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function add(){
  var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
  var tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'), sum = 0;
  for(var i=1,l=tr.length; i<l; i++){
    var inputs = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('input'), sub = 1;
    for(var n=1; n<3; n++){
      sub *= inputs[n].value;
    }
    sum += inputs[3].value = sub;
  }
  totalNode.innerHTML = sum;
}
```

Swap out `totalNode` with the `div` you want your total in. I would actually not use inputs for your subtotals as well, but that would require I rewrite this function. I also don't recommend putting JavaScript into your HTML like that, usually. You'll learn.

Comment: so I should call a separate javascript file?

Comment: I would use a closure, looping over `Element.onblur = function(){}`, but that could be more difficult in your case. Always use an external JavaScript file when possible, so it gets cached. Notice, that I would use an `onblur` Event.